# "Мраморная вязь фронтона истончена кружевом ремесла"?

Tags: выбор-слов

> И пусть такое положение храма мало расскажет о его пропорциях, зато
>   поможет внимательному путешественнику разглядеть подробную мраморную
>   вязь фронтона. Редко где она осталась в такой сохранности и была бы
>   столь истончена кружевом ремесла. Удивительная средневековая
>   кропотливость, где важен каждый элемент сам по себе, где нет детали
>   неважной.

Всё бы ничего... по отдельности, но вместе?!

На что можно заменить "истончена"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть, так: Редко где она осталась в такой сохранности и была бы столь **утончена кружевом искусного ремесла.**

Comment: Вас не смущает смешение наклонений: осталась и была бы утончена?

Comment: Сослагательное наклонение здесь имеет значение неуверенности, сомнения.  Возможно, что сам факт  сохранности мраморной вязи, как более вероятный, можно выразить изъявительным наклонением, но очень малую вероятность   сохранения столь искусного мастерства автор обозначил сослагательным наклонением.

Answer (score 1):

На что можно заменить "истончена"?

Украшена, изукрашена, декорирована.